# BigQuery: Run queries to create table and append to the table if table exist

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to run query to create a table if it does not exist, and append to the table if the table already exists? I like to write a single query to create or append. Note: I am using Admin console for now, will be using API eventually.

I have following query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_1.dataset_1.tabe_1`
 OPTIONS(
   description="Some desc"
 ) AS
 SELECT *
 FROM source_table
```

I get following error:

```
A table named project_1.dataset_1.tabe_1 already exists.
```

Answer (score 4):

Above query creates a table named 'table_1' if it does not exist under 'project_1.dataset_1', and append to the table if the table already exists.

```
IF
  (
  SELECT
    COUNT(1)
  FROM
    `project_1.dataset_1.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
  WHERE
    table_id='table_1') = 0 
THEN
    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
      `project_1.dataset_1.table_1` AS
    SELECT
      'apple' AS item,
      'fruit' AS category
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'leek',
      'vegetable';
  
ELSE
    INSERT
      `project_1.dataset_1.table_1` ( item,
        category )
    SELECT
      'lettuce' AS item,
      'vegetable' AS category
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'orange',
      'fruit';
END IF;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this that doesn't require effective duplication of the query?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it may be a good opportunity to leverage scripting within a single query to accomplish your needs.

See [this page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#beginexception) for adding control flow to a query to handle an error (e.g. if the table create fails due to existing). For the exception case, you could then [INSERT ... SELECT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#insert_examples) statement as needed.

You can do this via the API as well if you prefer.  Simply issue a tables.get equivalent appropriate to the particular library/language you choose and see if the table exists, and then insert the appropriate query based on that outcome of that check.